# Why it is not performing the maths in this case?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext, spinner

I have a strange situation I am faced with. This should be a unit converter but it always puts in the textview the input from the edittext without performing the maths.
The test is to operate a conversion from the number in the edittext and to report the result in the text of the textview. Now it displays in the textview what I wrote in edittext. Thank you for your time.

```
entepublic class lunghezze extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  EditText et1;
  TextView tv1;
  Spinner spinner1,spinner2;

  Button btnAdd;
  String oper = "";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.converter);

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.lunghezza, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.lunghezza, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);


    // find the elements
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);      
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);           
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    // set a listener
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);     
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double num1 = 0;

    double resdelta = 0;
    double res = 0;
    double resx2 = 0;

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(et1.getText().toString())) {
      return;
    }

    String a = et1.getText().toString().trim();
    num1 = a.isEmpty()? Double.NaN:Double.parseDouble(a);

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:        

        String s1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String s2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

      if (s1+s2.equals( "IardeIarde") != null){
          res=num1;

      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "IardeLeghe") != null){
          res= 0.0005*num1;

      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "IardeMetri") != null){
          res= 0.91*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "IardeMiglia terrestri") != null){
          res= 0.0005*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "IardePollici") != null){
          res= 36*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);


      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "LegheIarde") != null){
          res= 5280*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);              
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "LegheLeghe") != null){
          res=num1;
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "LegheMetri") != null){
          res= 4828*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "LegheMiglia terrestri") != null){
          res= 3*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "LeghePollici") != null){
          res= 190080*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);              

      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "MetriIarde") != null){
          res= 1.02*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);              
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "MetriLeghe") != null){
          res= 0.0002*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "MetriMetri") != null){
          res=num1;
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "MetriMiglia terrestri") != null){
          res= 0.0006*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "MetriPollici") != null){
          res= 39.3*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);


      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "Miglia terrestriIarde") != null){
          res= 1760*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);              
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "Miglia terrestriLeghe") != null){
          res= 0.33*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "Miglia terrestriMetri") != null){
          res= 1609.3*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "Miglia terrestriMiglia terrestri") != null){
          res=num1;
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "Miglia terrestriPollici") != null){
          res= 63360*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);


      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "PolliciIarde") != null){
          res= 0.027*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);              
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "PolliciLeghe") != null){
          res= 0.0000052*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "PolliciMetri") != null){
          res= 0.0254*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "PolliciMiglia terrestri") != null){
          res= 0.000015*num1;
          tv1.setText("" + res);
      } else if (s1+s2.equals( "PolliciPollici") != null){
          res=num1;           

      } else {

      }           

      break;

    default:
      break;
    }

    tv1.setText("" + res);

  }
}
```

Comment: You can find an answer for your question faster by debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Your string comparisons look very wrong:

```
s1 + s2.equals("IardeIarde") != null
```

This appends `s1` to the value of `s2.equals("IardeIarde")`, which is a boolean value. I have no idea why you are then comparing against null, as seeing you will get `true` or `false` in the string, it will always pass the comparison. If you were trying to compare the boolean with null, well, that just doesn't work.

You probably want to store `s1 + s2` in a variable, maybe something more descriptive than `s3` and invoke just `equals` when comparing.

```
String descriptiveName = s1 + s2;
if (descriptiveName.equals("IardeLeghe"))
    ...
```

If Java for Android supports it (I don't know, it's in Java 7 and above), you could make your code cleaner by switching on the string:

```
switch (s1 + s2) {
    case "IardeLeghe":
        ...
        break;
    case "IardeLeghe":
        ...
        break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hell, you can probably bracket it like this: `(s1 + s2.equals("IardeIarde"))`.

Comment: Makes a change from == vs .equals() I suppose

Comment: @theGreenCabbage He's more likely looking for `(s1 + s2).equals("IardeIarde")`.

Answer (score 0):

Like Zong Zheng Li has said, `s1 + s2.equals("IardeIarde") != null` is basically saying:

`s1` the string adds `s2.equals("IardeIarde")` the boolean `!= null`. You would most likely have gotten a warning just by that.

`if()` statements take the condition of `true` or `false`, or `1` or `0`. Your probably won't even compile in the get-go.

Perhaps you are looking at this:

```
String s3 = s1 + s2;
if(s3.equals("Whatever")){
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: I don't think it triggers any warnings, and probably compiles fine as well. Also `if` doesn't evaluate integers in Java.

Comment: Since `s1` is a String, and `s2.equals("Whatever")` is a boolean, wouldn't you have `type` difference by adding them together?

Comment: If the first term is a string, the second term can be anything. `+` will concatentate the string with the second term's value from `toString()`.